# How can I open a closed question?

Tags: support

I have edited [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/49220/is-parthenogenesis-possible-in-human-beings) which was put on hold previously. Is there any possibility of opening the question. If there is,how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way: Closed questions can be nominated for re-opening by users which have at least a reputation of 3000 (see [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) for details.

You can also ask in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1997/the-biosphere) for someone to help you.